# Spring Boot 1.5.4 with STOMP simple broker unable to scale up to 1000 concurrent connections

Tags: spring, stomp

I have project with Spring Boot 1.5.4 RELEASE + STOMP (simple broker) + SockJS. I was able to get good throughput up to 300 concurrent subscribers. Now I need to scale up to 1000 concurrent SockJS subscribers. I am getting frequent STOMP session getting closed, and at some point it stops responding to clients.

I don't see the web application hanging. It's responding to other API pretty well and memory and CPU usage is also moderate.

We tried moving to STOMP broker relay, but that seems to have even worse stability with frequent disconnections and OutOfMemory with ActiveMQ.

I am not sure where its blocking it as its in-memory broker should scale up to available heap.

Kindly help me in finding the root cause. It seems like I am missing something.

Comment: For what it's worth, just because you have resources (e.g. CPU and memory) available that doesn't mean the software (i.e. Spring's simple STOMP broker) will actually be able to use it. There could be other bottlenecks as a consequence of the architecture itself.

Comment: What version of ActiveMQ did you try using?